# On explaining QM by modeling the observation mechanism using a density operator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, resource-recommendations, density-operator, foundations

I just have some elementary thoughts on the foundations of QM, based on modeling the observation mechanism by a density operator. A density operator is a weighted sum of orthogonal projections on the basis elements of a unitary basis, with weights interpreted as probabilities. If you have a density operator $P$, and an observable $A$, the expected value of $A$ for the system $P$ is:

$tr(PA)$

and so on... Let's take a QM system with $n$ degrees of freedom. Before imposing a specific hamiltonian, the theory is $U(n)$ invariant, but after imposing a specific hamiltonian $H$, and assuming all the eigenvalues of $H$ are distinct, the symmetry of the theory gets reduced from $U(n)$ to a Cartan torus $T^n$, i.e. the product of $n$ copies of $U(1)$ (the stabilizer of $H$ in $U(n)$).

Anyway, these are just some trivial thought, and I am sure they are known. I would like to find a book or books which take on this approach for the exposition of QM. Is anyone aware of some QM books that take on this approach?

Comment: Which approach?

Comment: well, I meant, more or less the standard approach using hermitian operators and so on, but emphasizing the role that density operators have in the formalism. You see, when I took a course in QM many years ago, density operators were not mentioned. You could write a state as a linear combination of eigenstates, but we did not use density operators are all. Also, interpreting the observation mechanism as a density operator sounds interesting. I don't know, maybe it is too trivial for the experts... I don't know. Any constructive comments will be helpful.

Comment: The book of Asher Peres starts by inferring the density operator formalism only from Stern-Gerlach thought experiments.  Very impressive.  (And it demonstrates that in fact the density operator approach is the one which one can infer from experiments.)

Comment: @NorbertSchuch: Thank you so much! It does sound like the book has the approach I am looking for.